# jQuery not working properly

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part

In the `editform.aspx` of an item, I am trying to use jQuery to cause a pop up to go off anytime a field is changed (sort of silly, but once I get this to work, I plan on moving to doing more). However, it does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(“select [title=’Option’]”).change( function() {
            alert("yes");
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

I currently have this file linked in the content editor. There is a select field with title being Option in my SharePoint document, so I am not sure what the problem is. The error I receive is the following

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a javascript parsing error. Possibly your quotes. Try to replace ” by " and ’ by ' ?

Comment: @GertBraspenning I agree, the code sample seems to use `“`instad of `"`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$("select [title='Option']".on('change', function(){
alert("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @cubanGuy answer..

try

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type=text/javascript>
    alert("yes");
</script >
```

If that works, then you have a typo in your code.

You could try to set "onchange" in the html code:
HTML

```
<select title="Option" id="iCard" onchange="SetCard(this)">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Yes</option>
<option value="1">no</option>
```

JS

```
function SetCard() {
    alert("changing!!");
};
```

[JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbtcqyy7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your code in "content place holder main" in editform.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you are referencing to the js file, just remove those lines from the js file, use them only when embedding in HTML or ASPX page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type=text/javascript>
Your function
</script>
```